# File Upload php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

So I am trying to upload files to the database through php here is the code

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="uploadimage.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="tag"/>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
    $target = "files/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

    $name=$_POST['tag'];
    $file=($_FILES['file']['name']); 

    mysql_connect("localhost","Bluesir9","Bluesir9","website");
    mysql_query("Insert into files values('$name','$file');");

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target))
    {
        echo "The File ".basename($_FILES['file']['name'])."has been uploaded";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "Sorry there was an error";
    }
?>
```

when I check the target folder the files are there, but I cant find the files on the database returns an empty result set when I query it through phpMyAdmin.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do no error checking in your code. Check mysql_error() to see what the error is.

Comment: You're aware you're wide open to SQL injection, right?

Comment: It's somewhere around INSERT statement. try it with mysql_error()

Comment: what your files table looks like ?

Comment: In addition to what @RocketHazmat said, you have to use 'mysqli' instead of 'mysql'. It is really deprecated.

Comment: does files have a `id` column per chance? include the column names in your insert query

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty two columns: one called tag-varchar and the other called file-BLOB

Comment: You're not [properly escaping values](http://bobby-tables.com/php), creating several severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You're also using the deprecated `mysql_query` which should not be used in new applications because it's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) shows how to avoid making these sorts of mistakes.

Comment: @Bluesir9: You're saving the file name as a BLOB?  Why?

Comment: @RocketHazmat no blob is for the file

Comment: @Bluesir9: You are inserting the file's name into the database, not the file itself.  `$file=($_FILES['file']['name']);`  You shouldn't be storing the file in the database, just its name/path.  Leave the files in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the target files are there in folder, and if you can't find the files on the database then obvious thing should be to check `insert` query.

Please check syntax of insert query

```
mysql_query("Insert into files values('$name','$file')");
```

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment.

Comment: @Bluesir9 ,Glad it worked.I would appriciate if you upvote and mark the answer as correct ,so that others will find it very easy